# Get Day And Month portion of culture specific date

Tags: c#, .net

When using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat to get local date formats, is there a built in way to get only the day and month portion of the date returned by the local ShortTimePattern? e.g. dd/MM

Basically, in my razor view, I am doing something like this:

```
@someObject.Date.ToString("dd/MM")
```

But now need to make it work with the current culture so am hoping to find a way to provide a dynamic format mask based on the current culture. Imagine something like:

```
@someObject.Date.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePatternNoYear)
```

Comment: I'm confused.. you want the day and month from a time format ... ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I need to return just the days and month of a date, but in the appropriate culture-specific way. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you show us what you're attempting to do/what you've tried? You've mentioned `ShortTimePattern` but that has nothing to do with retrieving the day and month of a `DateTime` object.. (which, by the way, has `Day` and `Month` properties..).

Comment: Yep, I will update the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786886/custom-culture-aware-date-format-in-net

Answer (score 3):

Setting the month and day pattern for each culture is bad news.  The [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in this case says to leverage each culture's date-time format, not repeat (and possibly contradict) it with a custom `MonthDayPattern`.

Instead leverage the [Short Date ("d") format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) to get the month and day in the proper order and properly separated for the culture in question, and then whack the year (and its separator).

```
var de = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE").DateTimeFormat;
var uk = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB").DateTimeFormat;
var us = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat;

var now = DateTime.Now;
var yearNow = now.Year.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
const string yearPattern = "(^{0}{1}|{1}{0}$)"; // {0} = year, {1} = date separator

var deDate = now.ToString("d", de);
var deYearlessDate =
    Regex.Replace(
        deDate,
        String.Format(yearPattern, yearNow, de.DateSeparator),
        "");
// or a double String.Replace instead of a Regex.Replace
//var deYearlessDate =
//    deDate.Replace(de.DateSeparator + yearNow, "").Replace(yearNow + de.DateSeparator, "");

var ukDate = now.ToString("d", uk);
var ukYearlessDate =
    Regex.Replace(
        ukDate,
        String.Format(yearPattern, yearNow, uk.DateSeparator),
        "");
// or a double String.Replace instead of a Regex.Replace
//var ukYearlessDate =
//    ukDate.Replace(uk.DateSeparator + yearNow, "").Replace(yearNow + uk.DateSeparator, "");

var usDate = now.ToString("d", us);
var usYearlessDate =
    Regex.Replace(
        usDate,
        String.Format(yearPattern, yearNow, us.DateSeparator),
        "");
// or a double String.Replace instead of a Regex.Replace
//var usYearlessDate =
//    usDate.Replace(us.DateSeparator + nowYear, "").Replace(nowYear + us.DateSeparator, "");

Console.WriteLine(deYearlessDate); // 02.04
Console.WriteLine(ukYearlessDate); // 02/04
Console.WriteLine(usYearlessDate); // 4/2
```

Comment: I've included this inside a generic method with the date and country as params, and it works nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to find your current culture and update the DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern.

[Custom culture aware date format in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786886/custom-culture-aware-date-format-in-net) said that ShortDatePattern ("d") was unreliable and suggested the following method:

```
private static string FindMonthDayOnly(System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci)
{
  string shortPattern = ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
  while(shortPattern[0] != 'd' && shortPattern[0] != 'M')
  {
    shortPattern = shortPattern.Substring(1);
    if(shortPattern.Length == 0)
      return ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
  }
  while(shortPattern[shortPattern.Length - 1] != 'd' && shortPattern[shortPattern.Length - 1] != 'M')
  {
    shortPattern = shortPattern.Substring(0, shortPattern.Length - 1);
    if(shortPattern.Length == 0)
      return ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
  }
  return shortPattern;
}
```

Then all you have to do is find somewhere convenient to run something like this (think carefully about background threads etc as this will only work with the current thread):

```
var culture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);

var newMonthDayString = FindMonthDayOnly(culture);

culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern = newMonthDayString;

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Thanks for everyone's input. This seems to be working but please comment if you see any obvious issues with the solution.

Comment: There is little reason to loop through the `ShortDatePattern`, let alone twice; and this seems to effectively yield the same results and DRY adherence as the `Regex.Replace` (or double-`String.Replace`) solution I offered; but TMTOWDI.  Glad you found a way not to RY that you like. :}

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Extension method to display only Month and day depending of the CultureInfo, hope it helps:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return a date formatted MonthDay depending of the current application cutlure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="datetime">The datetime to parse</param>
    /// <returns>A Month day string representation</returns>
    public static string ToMonthDay(this DateTime datetime)
    {
        // Get the current culture of the application
        var culture = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

        // Get the format depending of the culture of the application
        var output = culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

        // Remove the Year from from the date format
        var format = output.Replace("Y", "").Replace("y", "");

        // Remove any character before or after in the text string which is not a number
        Regex rgx = new Regex("^[^a-zA-Z0-9]|[^a-zA-Z0-9]$");
        format = rgx.Replace(format, "");

        return datetime.ToString(format);
    }
```

And the usage:

```
DateTime dateToDisplay = new DateTime(2009, 01, 31);


Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(dateToDisplay.ToMonthDay());

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(dateToDisplay.ToMonthDay());
```