# Is there a way to supply Month/Day in a culture aware manner?

Tags: c#, .net, date, .net-core

I need to show Month/Day in a culture aware manner, so that June 29, 2021 looks like `6/29` in US, `29.06` in Russia, `29/06` in Spain and so on.

The closest thing that I could come up with is this:

```
DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2021, 6, 29);
var cultureUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var cultureRU = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
var cultureES = new CultureInfo("es-ES");

Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d", cultureUS)); // 6/29/2021
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d", cultureRU)); // 29.06.2021
Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString("d", cultureES)); // 29/06/2021
```

And then I could remove the year:

```
static string RemoveYear(string dateString, DateTime thisDate) {
    string s = dateString.Replace(thisDate.ToString("yyyy"), "");
    return s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

This looks hacky to me since it makes lots of assumptions about the format of the date.

So is there a system supplied way to display Month/Day with culture applied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Day And Month portion of culture specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826877/get-day-and-month-portion-of-culture-specific-date)

Comment: @gunr2171 It's employing a slightly less hacky approach than mine, but still hacky.

Comment: June 29? How are you already in the future? :)

Comment: It seems this really doesn't work without some kind of hack. You can get all parts culture-dependent (including month or day names) or use one of `ToShortDate` or `ToLongDate`, but you can't get anything between. There should be a "Get me the date with these parts in a culture dependent order"-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use a combination of `ShortDatePattern` and `DateSeparator`. Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime thisDate = new DateTime(2021, 6, 29);
        
        var en = DayMonthPattern("en-US");
        Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString(en));

        var ru = DayMonthPattern("ru-RU");
        Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString(ru));

        var es = DayMonthPattern("es-ES");
        Console.WriteLine(thisDate.ToString(es));

    }
    
    public static string DayMonthPattern(string inCultureInfo){

        DateTimeFormatInfo myDTFI = new CultureInfo( inCultureInfo, false ).DateTimeFormat;

        // get the ShortDatePattern (eg dd.MM.yyyy)
        var shortDatePattern = myDTFI.ShortDatePattern;
        
        // split it on the culture's separator
        var components = shortDatePattern.Split(myDTFI.DateSeparator.ToCharArray());
        var newComponents = new List<string>();
        
        // pull out any references to a year component
        foreach(var component in components){
            if (!component.ToUpper().Contains("Y")){
                newComponents.Add(component);
            }
        }
        
        // put it back together with the culture's separator
        return string.Join(myDTFI.DateSeparator, newComponents);
    }
}
```

Output:

> 6/29

> 29.06

> 29/06

See:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FBjqan

Answer (score 0):

Careful now. Showing a date in a culture-aware format gets you nowhere in terms of ambiguity if the text surrounding it is still in English language. I don't know if that is your case, but I often see developers/designers falling into this trap. So, I pose the question: Is localized date format really what you want??

When I look at an application or website in English language it doesn't help me that the date format is from my own culture, because I would still be uncertain if that is the case. So it gets you exactly nowhere. `2/6`  (US), `6/2` (Spain) and `06.02` (Russia) are equally ambiguous.

Here is my **golden rule book** regarding date format:

- If the date is used in computer-to-computer communication:  Use ISO-8601 format.
- If the date is meant for human consumption (i.e. in a PDF, a UI, etc):

  - If the text surrounding the date is fully localized, meaning all surrounding text is in a language other than English:  Use whatever format applies in that culture. Use the other answers on this page.
  - If the text surrounding the date is English: Use whatever date format you want as long as you *spell the month using letters, not digits*. You dig?  For example, any of the following will work just fine: `7 February, 2022`, `February 7, 2022`, `07 FEB 2022` etc. In your example, I would use `07-FEB` or something like that (since you don't want the year).

If you don't want to spend money on localizing the UI (meaning you only have an English version): **Use letters for the month** and all your users will instantly understand it. I promise you that you will not get support calls from say a German speaking user because she sees a date as `07 FEB 2022` in an otherwise English UI. She will understand it, so will the US person, so will the Chinese person, etc.

**Do not localize date format if the UI is in English !! .. but be sure to use letters for the month**