# Change the short date pattern of DateTime.ToString() method in .NET

Tags: .net, datetime-format

I want to show a DateTime object formatted as "5/30" (without the year), and it should work across all locales, meaning that the current locale is French, it should show as "30/5".

I found that none of the standard format specifier fits my needs. I tried the custom format specifier "m", but it outputs "May 30". I want the month to show as number instead of word.

How do I do it?

Comment: All the formatting options are detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). For month, the format key is `"M"`, little `"m"` is actually for minutes.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786886/custom-culture-aware-date-format-in-net

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
 string sz = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/dd");
```

it will produce your desired output

Comment: it won't show correctly in French, for example, because French show day before month.